# Query Parameters twitch API

Tags: javascript, api, xmlhttprequest

This query works, but i want to add some optionnals parameters.

```
Alert.prototype.getUserFollowedChannels = async function (user) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>{
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.open('GET', 'https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/users/' + user+ '/follows/channels?client_id=' + this.clientId, true);
            //xhr.open('GET', 'https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/users/' + user+ '/follows/channels?client_id=' + this.clientId+'?limit=100', true); // try with what i want
            xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (xhr.readyState != 4 || xhr.status != 200) return;
                var follows = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
                if (follows) resolve(follows);
                else resolve("none");
            }
            xhr.send();
        })
}
```

There is the doc of my query : https://dev.twitch.tv/docs/v5/reference/users/#get-user-follows

Comment: can you specify the optional parameters? How are they defined? Please add some more example code.

Comment: Parameters details are in  the doc : https://dev.twitch.tv/docs/v5/reference/users/#get-user-follows

Comment: You can create a function that accepts an object (key:value) and iterates over it, then creates a query parameter string, and returns it, appending it to the url

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like [query-string](https://www.npmjs.com/package/query-string)